# AudioKit microphone does not init on first run

Tags: ios, audiokit

Good afternoon,

I am using the latest version of AudioKit (4.9 Master Branch) with Xcode 11.3 and am running into a strange permission problem. When a user launches an app for the first time, the OS asks for permission to use the microphone. After the user selects "Allow", the microphone does not work, but if you force quit the app and relaunch it the microphone works fine.

I created a function to test the state of the permission and placed it in viewDidLoad() :

```
func checkMic() {
    switch AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().recordPermission {
    case AVAudioSessionRecordPermission.granted:
        print("Permission granted")
    case AVAudioSessionRecordPermission.denied:
        print("Pemission denied")
    case AVAudioSessionRecordPermission.undetermined:
        print("Request permission here")
        AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().requestRecordPermission({ (granted) in
            print("Mic Enabled")


        })
    @unknown default:
        print("Not Working")
    }
}
```

The function is only triggered during the first run but I have already initialized my AudioKit singleton class by this point. I have tried to reinitialize with no success. I have not encountered this before and am wondering if anyone else is experiencing this change or had a suggestion for it.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that both the AKAnalizer and AKMicrophone are disabled when when iOS asks for permission to use the microphone. I needed to start both again. Hope this helps anyone in the same situation.

```
var audioCore = AudioCore.sharedInstance()

func checkMic() {
    switch AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().recordPermission {
    case AVAudioSessionRecordPermission.granted:
        print("Permission granted")
    case AVAudioSessionRecordPermission.denied:
        print("Pemission denied")
    case AVAudioSessionRecordPermission.undetermined:
        print("Request permission here")
        AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().requestRecordPermission({ (granted) in
            print("Mic Enabled")
            self.audioCore.microphone.start()
            self.audioCore.analyzer.start()
            print(self.audioCore.microphone.isStarted)
            print(self.audioCore.analyzer.isStarted)

        })
    @unknown default:
        print("Not Working")
    }
```